# Is there something like Collectable typeclass?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, scala-cats

I noticed that containers like `Option`, `OptionT`, `fs2.Stream` have the following method:

```
def collect[B](f: PartialFunction[A, B])(implicit F: Functor[F]): OptionT[F, B] =
    OptionT(F.map(value)(_.collect(f)))
```

So I'm curious if there is something like `Collectable` typeclass:

```
trait Collectable[F[_]] {
  def collect[A, B](fa: F[A])(pf: PartialFunction[A, B]): F[B]
}
```

It seems quite useful to me and is pretty straightforward to implement, but anyway is there something with similar functionality included in `cats/scalaz` already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Foldable](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/Foldable.scala) typeclass seems to come pretty close to what you want. It has a method `collectFirst`, with the following signature:

```
  def collectFirst[A, B](fa: F[A])(pf: PartialFunction[A, B]): Option[B] =
```

and a curious implementation:

```
    foldRight(fa, Eval.now(Option.empty[B])) { (a, lb) =>
      // trick from TraversableOnce, 
      // used to avoid calling both isDefined and apply (or calling lift)
      val x = pf.applyOrElse(a, sentinel)
      if (x.asInstanceOf[AnyRef] ne sentinel) Eval.now(Some(x.asInstanceOf[B]))
      else lb
    }.value
```

where `sentinel` is a strange little function that always returns itself:

```
private val sentinel: Function1[Any, Any] = 
  new scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1[Any, Any]{ 
    def apply(a: Any) = this 
  }
```

Those two last code snippets are supposed to provide some motivation to not reimplement `collectFirst` multiple times.

Comment: Thanks, did not know that. But is it possible to implement the `collect` via `fold`? Or only `collectFirst` is possible?

Comment: @St.Antario Seems as if it should be possible to emulate `collect` with an `filter` (by `isDefinedAt`), followed by a map (actual `apply`). But I don't see it in the current API...